# QDialog flash back after create

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QListWidget` on my `QMainWindow`, and I connect the `itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)` signals to a slot like the following code:

```
connect(listWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(popUpMyDialog(QListWidgetItem*)));
```

My `popUpMyDialog(QListWidgetItem*)` function is like:

```
QMyDialog *myDialog = new QMyDialog(this);
myDialog->show();
```

`QMyDialog` is a class which I inherent from `QDialog`, and no operation except `ui->setupUi(this);` was done.

But when I try to double click on the item of `QListWidget`, the `myDialog` flashed and disappear very soon.

So I had tried to write some code to judge if the `myDialog` is deleted like that:

```
QMyDialog *myDialog = new QMyDialog(this);
connect(myDialog, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this, SLOT(handleQMyDialogClose(QObject*)));
myDialog->show();
```

and the slots function `handleQMyDialogClose(QObject*)` just do:

```
qDebug() << "myDialog is closed";
```

When I double click on the item of item of QListWidget, the console print `myDialog is closed`, which means the myDialog object is deleted, but I don't delete the pointer, so I feel confused.

1. I Googled it and tried to setModal attributes to `myDialog` , but it take no effect.
2. I tried to copy the same code to my Mac, the strange thing is that it runs perfect.
3. I tried to add a for loop in my `popUpMyDialog(QListWidgetItem*)` like that:

   ```
   QMyDialog *myDialog = new QMyDialog(this);
   connect(myDialog, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this, SLOT(handleQMyDialogClose(QObject*)));
   myDialog->show();
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {qDebug() << i;}
   ```

   to block the thread, and find that the `myDialog` window work prefect, but if I comment the for loop code, it flash back again.

So, I want to know what error happened to my code, and how I can try to handle it.

My coding environment is:
 `Windows 10` and `Mac OS X 10.10.4 Yosemite`, the version of Qt is `Qt5.5.0`, and on my Windows , the Qt runs with `mingw`.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have the following method:

```
void Foo::popUpMyDialog(QListWidgetItem*) {
  QMyDialog *myDialog = new QMyDialog(this);
  myDialog->show();
}
```

The only reason why the dialog would get prematurely destroyed is if the instance of `Foo`, that the dialog is a child of, got destructed.

To troubleshoot the issue, first try to create a parentless dialog:

```
void Foo::popUpMyDialog(QListWidgetItem*) {
  QMyDialog *myDialog = new QMyDialog;
  myDialog->show();
}
```

If that dialog remains visible, then you know that you gave it a wrong, short-lived parent. The solution would be to find another parent. To avoid leaking the dialogs, you can give the dialog a `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute.

Comment: I tried to create a parentless dialog and it takes no effect too.

Comment: @kemiya You need to make a copy of your project and start minimizing it, so as to leave just enough code to show this problem and nothing else. Your question doesn't have enough detail as it stands to figure out why the issue happens. The only idea I have is that you're blocking the event loop. After you've "shown" the dialog, pause the execution in the debugger and see whether `QApplication::exec` is on the call stack in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

QDialog has an [exec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) function that "blocks" the execution (as you do with your loop), to use instead of `show()` so your dialog can stay visible. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: `QDialog::exec()` is a bad idea. Please don't recommend such hacks.

Comment: @KubaOber please explain why?

Comment: I don't understand, how is exec() a hack ?

Comment: It is a hack because it creates a nested event loop, and suddenly all of your code that you never wished to look at becomes reentrant. And you have to audit it to show that it's safe! Never mind that this pseudo-synchronous state of mind is a bad place to be. If you keep writing code like that, you're setting yourself up for constant failure and constant battle. Real life is asynchronous. You have to tackle it head on. There are two valid reasons to use `exec` in Qt: 1. Starting an event loop in a thread that hitherto had none. 2. With `QDrag` since it doesn't offer an async api (sigh).

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link to provide more information about this? I can't find any. From what I understood, QDialog::exec() processes the event loop the same way QApplication::exec() does, so I don't see the problem (and I have never heard of it).

Comment: @dydil Just think about it. `QApplication::exec` is already on the call stack. The second `exec` will be called from a random slot or event handler that can be trivially re-entered from the nested `exec` (you entered it once, who's to stop you from entering it again?). That's why it's a horrible hack. Again, the world is asynchronous - the nested `exec()` hides it from you and encourages spaghetti code, heightened resource usage (an extra page on the stack just to recurse the event loop), and leaks reentrancy where you expect none. It's a no-no. Thoroughly bad idea.